# Dojo JsonRest appends &name=* to target URL

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form, jsonreststore

I try to use the Dojo JsonRest to fill a dijit.form.select Box and I use the following code:

`var stateStore = new JsonRest({target: "ip-address/activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions?startableByUser=kermit", headers: {"Authorization": "Basic a2VybWl0Omtlcm1pdA=="}});`

The Problem is, that the target-url is extended with `&name=*` 
Therefore, the Server sees the following request: `ipaddress/activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions?startableByUser=kermit&name=*`

I can not figure out where the `&name=*`  comes from.

I read this article: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/dojox-data-JsonRestStore-appends-quot-Title-quot-to-my-target-url-why-td2012228.html and used the allowNoTrailingSlash-Attribute without success.

My question is how I can avoid that the target url gets altered. We must avoid that `&name=*`  gets attached at the end of the url.

Thanks abd best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault because I used dijit/form/FilteringSelect instead of dijit/form/Select. FilteringSelect allows you to type in letters. Those letters were appended to the url.