# DOJO JsonRest - Unable to Alter Target URL After onClick

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have this working with `FilteringSelect`:

```
var jsonStore = new JsonRest  ({
    target: "/ajax_script/autocomplete?term1=" + foo1 + "&term2=" + foo2
});
```

But when i click a button which changes the value of `term2` to `foo3`, `target` always remains with `foo2`.

I can see in the console that `term2`'s value is indeed changed to `foo3`, both before and after `jsonStore` is instantiated, so i'm wondering if the jsonStore object is cached somehow.

Is this an improper use of `target`? Is there a way around this, or perhaps an alternative?

**EDIT for Harpreet's Answer**

I did experiment with this method of passing params to the `target` url, but i found it to be incompatible with `FilteringSelect`.

My understanding of `FilteringSelect` is that it passes the `searchAttr` property value to the JsonRest URL, so that if my `searchAttr` is "term", the data entered in the input from the user (via `FilteringSelect`) then gets passed as "term=someusrinput".

In my case i needed to pass further parameters, but using `store.query()` results in a separate request to the `JsonRest` URL which doesn't also include the "term" from `FiteringSelect`. The `store.query` request includes "term1, term2, term3" parameters, which fails because it doesn't include "term" (from `FilteringSelect`) and then the `FilteringSelect` request includes "term", which fails because it doesn't include "term1, term2,term3"!

I need to pass additional parameters to the `target` URL, which works by modifying the `target` URL with a query string - the `FilteringSelect` term is passed and combined with the query string variables.

The problem i face is that i'm unable to "re-query" via `JsonRest` with new parameters for the query string modified via an `onClick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right way for appending params to the URL.

You don't need to modify target.

Check this example

```
require(["dojo/store/JsonRest"], function(JsonRest) {

    var store = new JsonRest({
        target: "/ajax_script/autocomplete"
    });

    store.query({
        term1: "foo1",
        term2: "foo2",
    }, {});
    //URL - "/ajax_script/autocomplete?term1=foo1&term2=foo2

});
```

Dojo will automatically append you params `term1` and `term2` to the parent url for every `get`, `put`, `add` and another method

Check the resulted request URL of this [example](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#id8)

**Edit**

> FilteringSelect + JSONRestStore

What you are trying to achieve is not possible with **FilteringSelect**. For this you should use **Select**.

> Issue is **FilteringSelect** appends `*` at each word you type in the
>   **Textbox** of **FilteringSelect**. eg: if you type `k` it will become `k*`. When it is passed to **JsonRestStore** for query **it will not
>   treat it as special input and will not modify it for intelligent
>   search but use it as exact Pattern you want to match wtth the result.**
>
> ```
> var query =  {
>     valueToSearch: "k*"
> }
> ```
>
> and your **Url** become: **example.com?valueToSearch=k***
>
> ```
> "k*" == "kite" //false
> ```

**Instead of** using **FileringSelect** you should use **Select** and then your query will be

```
var query =  {
    valueToSearch: "kite"
}
```

> and your **Url** become: **example.com?valueToSearch=kite**
>
> kite == kite //true, as "kite" will current selected value, not entered by user

I have also created this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harpreetsingh/zwvrphd2/1/), with which you can play around and check your result using console's

Check this [Another Question From SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304954/dojo-jsonrest-appends-name-to-target-url?rq=1)

**Possible Solutions that I can suggest you are**

1. Use **Select** widget
2. Modify - **JsonRestStore** as per your requirement.
3. Pre-Load all data from the Remote server using JSON request and add it to a **Memory** Store and then use it without any headache. You can then use **FilteringSelect** without any Issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Harpreet Singh - i did experiment with `store.query`, but it doesn't seem to work for me in combination with `FilteringSelect`.  I've edited my question with a fuller explanation.

Comment: well, eventually this got some attention again, and we got it working thanks to your answer!